# Firestore security rules request.query.orderBy not working

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Firestore security rule

```
allow list: if request.query.limit <=30
&& request.query.orderBy == 'date'
```

Android code

```
db.collection(COL)
.orderBy("date", Direction.DESCENDING)
.limit(30)
.get()
```

The above code works fine when I removed request.query.orderBy in security rule.

How to fix it?

Comment: Can you show the code that doesn't work against these rules?

Comment: Hi Frank, thanks for the response. I updated the code in the question.

Comment: Hmm.... I'm not sure what's going wrong there. Upvoted in hopes that somebody else spots the problem.

Comment: ok... thanks! I found the same question posted by another user, but still there is no answer. Can you please test request.query.orderBy working as expected or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer.

We should treat request.query.orderBy has Map.

```
request.query.orderBy.date == 'DESC'
```